# Code in C to display LEDs when a number is input

Tags: c, switch-statement

The code below should take the input, store it then display LEDs that give the number as a display. However it gives random LEDs, not the correct one. I've checked a few things but I can't see what's wrong, can you help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
   /* Declare a data variable for each pixel. */
   int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 =0;
   int b1, b2, b3, b4, b5 =0;
   int c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 =0;
   int d1, d2, d3, d4, d5 =0;
   int e1, e2, e3, e4, e5 =0;
   int f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 =0;
   int g1, g2, g3, g4, g5 =0;
   int h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 =0;
   int i1, i2, i3, i4, i5 =0;
   int j1, j2, j3, j4, j5 =0;
   int k1, k2, k3, k4, k5 =0;
   int l1, l2, l3, l4, l5 =0;


   /* Collect the data from stdin and store in a string */

      char str[6];
      scanf("%s", str);
      int a = str[0] - '0';
      int b = str[1] - '0';
      int c = str[2] - '0';
      int d = str[3] - '0';

   /* Change the pixels to store the shape of the numbers to be displayed */   

      switch ( a ) {
      case 0:
        a1, b1, c1, a2, c2, a3, c3, a4, c4, a5, b5, c5 = 1;
        break;
      case 1:
        c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 = 1;
        break;
      case 2:
        a1, b1, c1, c2, a3, b3, c3, a4, a5, b5, c5 = 1;
        break;
      case 3:
        a1, b1, c1, c2, a3, b3, c3, c4, a5, b5, c5 = 1;
        break;
      case 4:
        a1, c1, a2, c2, a3, b3, c3, b4, b5 = 1;
        break;
      case 5:
        a1, b1, c1, a2, a3, b3, c3, c4, a5, b5, c5 = 1;
        break;
      case 6:
        a1, b1, c1, a2, a3, b3, c3, a4, c4, a5, b5, c5 = 1;
        break;
      case 7:
        a1, b1, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 = 1;
        break;
      case 8:
        a1, b1, c1, a2, c2, a3, b3, c3, a4, c4, a5, b5, c5 = 1;
        break;
      case 9:
        a1, b1, c1, a2, c2, a3, b3, c3, c4, c5 = 1;
        break; 
      default:
        printf("Please input a valid number");
        return 0;
          break;
}

switch ( b ) {
      case 0:
        d1, e1, f1, d2, f2, d3, f3, d4, f4, d5, e5, f5 = 1;
        break;
      case 1:
        f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 = 1;
        break;
      case 2:
        d1, e1, f1, f2, d3, e3, f3, d4, d5, e5, f5 = 1;
        break;
      case 3:
        d1, e1, f1, f2, d3, e3, f3, f4, d5, e5, f5 = 1;
        break;
      case 4:
        d1, f1, d2, f2, d3, e3, f3, e4, e5 = 1;
        break;
      case 5:
        d1, e1, f1, d2, d3, e3, f3, f4, d5, e5, f5 = 1;
        break;
      case 6:
        d1, e1, f1, d2, d3, e3, f3, d4, f4, d5, e5, f5 = 1;
        break;
      case 7:
        d1, e1, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 = 1;
        break;
      case 8:
        d1, e1, f1, d2, f2, d3, e3, f3, d4, f4, d5, e5, f5 = 1;
        break;
      case 9:
        d1, e1, f1, d2, f2, d3, e3, f3, f4, f5 = 1;
        break; 
      default:
        printf("Please input a valid number");
        return 0;
          break;
}

switch ( c ) {
      case 0:
        g1, h1, i1, g2, i2, g3, i3, g4, i4, g5, h5, i5 = 1;
        break;
      case 1:
        i1, i2, i3, i4, i5 = 1;
        break;
      case 2:
        g1, h1, i1, i2, g3, h3, i3, g4, g5, h5, i5 = 1;
        break;
      case 3:
        g1, h1, i1, i2, g3, h3, i3, i4, g5, h5, i5 = 1;
        break;
      case 4:
        g1, i1, g2, i2, g3, h3, i3, h4, h5 = 1;
        break;
      case 5:
        g1, h1, i1, g2, g3, h3, i3, i4, g5, h5, i5 = 1;
        break;
      case 6:
        g1, h1, i1, g2, g3, h3, i3, g4, i4, g5, h5, i5 = 1;
        break;
      case 7:
        g1, h1, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5 = 1;
        break;
      case 8:
        g1, h1, i1, g2, i2, g3, h3, i3, g4, i4, g5, h5, i5 = 1;
        break;
      case 9:
        g1, h1, i1, g2, i2, g3, h3, i3, i4, i5 = 1;
        break; 
      default:
        printf("Please input a valid number");
        return 0;
          break;
}

switch ( d ) {
      case 0:
        j1, k1, l1, j2, l2, j3, l3, j4, l4, j5, k5, l5 = 1;
        break;
      case 1:
        l1, l2, l3, l4, l5 = 1;
        break;
      case 2:
        j1, k1, l1, l2, j3, k3, l3, j4, j5, k5, l5 = 1;
        break;
      case 3:
        j1, k1, l1, l2, j3, k3, l3, l4, j5, k5, l5 = 1;
        break;
      case 4:
        j1, l1, j2, l2, j3, k3, l3, k4, k5 = 1;
        break;
      case 5:
        j1, k1, l1, j2, j3, k3, l3, l4, j5, k5, l5 = 1;
        break;
      case 6:
        j1, k1, l1, j2, j3, k3, l3, j4, l4, j5, k5, l5 = 1;
        break;
      case 7:
        j1, k1, l1, l2, l3, l4, l5 = 1;
        break;
      case 8:
        j1, k1, l1, j2, l2, j3, k3, l3, j4, l4, j5, k5, l5 = 1;
        break;
      case 9:
        j1, k1, l1, j2, l2, j3, k3, l3, l4, l5 = 1;
        break; 
      default:
        printf("Please input a valid number");
        return 0;
          break;
}

      /* Display the pixels in the correct order */

         if (a1 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (b1 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (c1 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (d1 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (e1 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (f1 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (g1 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (h1 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (i1 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (j1 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (k1 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (l1 == 1 )
            printf("O\n");
         else
            printf(" \n");

         if (a2 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (b2 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (c2 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (d2 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (e2 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (f2 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (g2 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (h2 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (i2 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (j2 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (k2 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (l2 == 1 )
            printf("O\n");
         else
            printf(" \n");

         if (a3 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (b3 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (c3 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (d3 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (e3 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (f3 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (g3 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (h3 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (i3 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (j3 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (k3 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (l3 == 1 )
            printf("O\n");
         else
            printf(" \n");

         if (a4 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (b4 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (c4 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (d4 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (e4 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (f4 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (g4 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (h4 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (i4 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (j4 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (k4 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (l4 == 1 )
            printf("O\n");
         else
            printf(" \n");

         if (a5 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (b5 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (c5 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (d5 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (e5 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (f5 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (g5 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (h5 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (i5 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (j5 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (k5 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");

         if (l5 == 1 )
            printf("O");
         else
            printf(" ");
}
```

Comment: April Fool's Day is still a few months in the future...

Comment: I'll give you points for giving it a go, but it's probably best that you read a decent book on C before moving on.

Comment: I'll have to give you bonus points for not using `void main()` or `system("pause")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

```
int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 =0;
```

That's only actually initialising a5, not any other of the variables, so a1 to a4 are uninitialised so will contain random values.

```
case 0:
        a1, b1, c1, a2, c2, a3, c3, a4, c4, a5, b5, c5 = 1;
```

You're not assigning any variables except c5 to 1.  You could do this instead though, which isn't much more code:

```
        a1 = b1 = c1 = a2 = c2 = a3 = c3 = a4 = c4 = a5 = b5 = c5 = 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

For each of these things:

```
c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 = 1;
```

If you're trying to set them all to 1. You need to do it like this:

```
c1 = 1;
c2 = 1;
c3 = 1;
c4 = 1;
c5 = 1;
```

or alternatively:

```
c1 = c2 = c3 = c4 = c5 = 1;
```

In other words, you need to set each one individually.

**That said, you should be using arrays to do this instead.**

Comment: The assignments can also be done by chaining the = operators, e.g. c1 = c2 = c3 = c4 = c5 = 1;  However, it really should be done using arrays.

Comment: @Ryan Yes that's true - except for in the declarations.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't read the whole code, but it's seems that you misunderstood the comma operator.
The line `a1, b1, c1, a2, c2, a3, c3, a4, c4, a5, b5, c5 = 1;`
 is exactly like `c5=1;`. if you want them all to be 1, you should write `a1= b1= c1= a2= c2= a3= c3= a4= c4= a5= b5= c5 = 1;`

Also, consider using array instead of all these vars.